# How to return fieldValue or data to a variable in with firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I hav two types of variables that I am trying to use in my code and I am struggling to make them not come back as `undefined`.

```
const destinationData = collectionData.doc('india');

let travelData =  destinationData.get()
            .then(doc => {
                if (!doc.exists) {
                    return res.status(404).send(msgNotFound);
                } else {
                    return doc.data();
                }
            })

console.log(travelData.name);
```

```
const passportData = collectionData.doc('australia');

let passportCountry = passportData.get('countryCode');

console.log(passportCountry);
```

Comment: `get()` is asynchronous and returns immediately with a promise.  `then()` also returns immediately with another promise.  You will need to deal with these promises using asynchronous programming patterns in JavaScript.

Comment: Do you have an example on how to do it with above? I'm still unsure what you mean.

Comment: This may help you in order to get a better idea of what Doug is mentioning in his comment: https://medium.com/@vladfr/use-cloud-firestore-with-async-bce875af0183